# Sqoop incremental lastmodified option

Tags: sqoop

Can we update sqoop.last.value in sqoop through scripts in automated way. It currently loads the run time. I dont want to miss the updates b/w runtime and source system update time. so looking to see if we can update the last value. I know manually we can do it, but looking for an automated way.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean manually?. You mean a feature in sqoop to update or a script which could update the value etc..

Comment: incremental.last.value is present in metastore.db.script(insert into sqoop_sessions ...) . Updating through sqoop or through script is fine. I am just looking ways to update it. Also one more issue what I see is for some jobs(I run totally 20 jobs), incremental.last.value not being updated in the metastore even though the job loads data in the table.

Comment: Do you mean `Sqoop job` command?